# Is it possible to have strongly typed parameter constraints in a constructor of a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I would like to define a generic class in C#:

```
public class MyService<TModel>
{
    public MyService(/*What to declare here?*/)
    {
    }
}
```

such that I can instantiate it like the following:

```
var service = new MyService<SomeModel>(m => m.SomeField);
```

where `SomeField` is restricted to be a field of `SomeModel`. Is this possible?

I know I can declare something similar for a method within the class but can't quite figure out how this can be done for constructors. For example, I can declare the following in `MyService`:

```
    public void SomeMethod<TMember>(Expression<Func<TModel, TMember>> member)
    {
    }
```

and be able to invoke it like this:

```
var service = new MyService<SomeModel>();
service.SomeMethod(m => m.SomeField);
```

and the compiler would complain if `SomeField` wasn't actually a field of `SomeModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public class MyService<TModel>
{
    public static MyService<TModel> Create<TMember>(Func<TModel, TMember> member)
    {
        return new MyServiceImpl<TMember>(member);
    }

    private class MyServiceImpl<TMember> : MyService<TModel>
    {
        private Func<TModel, TMember> member;
        public MyServiceImpl(Func<TModel, TMember> member)
        {
            this.member = member;
        }
    }
}
```

So now I can do this:

```
MyService<Foo> service = MyService<Foo>.Create(m => m.Name);
```

Note, that I don't need to specify the type of the member.

Here's my class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: +1 from me, I would have updated my answer with this but you had already solved guylegend problem before I came back to the computer.

Comment: Yes, I like this approach which is also what siride was alluding to. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You must put both `TModel` and `TMember` both in the `<>` in the constructor.

```
public class MyService<TModel, TMember>
{
    public MyService(Expression<Func<TModel, TMember>> member)
    {
    }
}
```

You can't create a constructor that uses extra generic parameters that are not part of the class like you can with a method.

Comment: Thanks. I see, but how would I instantiate `MyService` in this case?

Comment: Same way you would calling any generic constructor. The generic parameters declared in the class must be declared in the constructor: `MyService<SomeModel, SomeMemberType>`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I was hoping `SomeMemberType` can be inferred. This means I must know my field's type ahead of time. For example:

`var service = new MyService<Company, string>(m => m.Name);`

means that the field must be of type `string` whereas my method example above didn't have this restraint.

Comment: @guylegend: if you don't want to deal with that, then create a static factory method that calls the constructor internally. The static method can infer arguments, and would not require the class to have more generic parameters than strictly needed (i.e., you can get rid of TMember).

Comment: @guylegend - As soon as you had `m => m.SomeField` you were certainly constraining the member type at compile-time.

Comment: @Enigmativity, you're certainly right. I was just hoping it would look more elegant I suppose.

Comment: @guylegend - Take a look at my answer. I think I have an elegant solution.